# What is BihConsumerInterop?

Tags: workflow

A workflow completes its tasks, but is still shown as running. When looking at the Workflow history the last entry is:

```
An error has occurred in Workflow Name.
```

The SharePoint log has the following error at that time:

```
Area: SharePoint Foundation
Category: Workflow Infrastructure
Level: Unexpected
Message:
Load Workflow Assembly: System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
Could not load file or assembly 'BihConsumerInterop, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=48e046c834625a88'
or one of its dependencies.
The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'BihConsumerInterop, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=48e046c834625a88'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post on the MSDN Fora does suggest a resolution, it might work:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/a09957c6-d681-40b6-aed0-483f0831af57

Comment: Beat me by few minutes :)

Comment: Wifi at BPCUK is faster than I thought ;)

Comment: OK, but what is BihConsumerInterop?

Comment: Something used by the SP2010 Server Search infrastructure. Not much documentation out there on it, think it's internal code.

Comment: Is putting the DLL in the GAC as simple as copying it to the assembly folder? And, will we have to do this everytime we create a new server?

Comment: 1) Yes when the fusion cache viewer is enabled (you see all the assemblies, versions and cultures in one view when you go to c:\windows\assembly), 2) Probably yes, to be safe

Answer (score 0):

1. BihConsumerInterop not deployed to GAC
2. BihConsumerInterop not build for "Any CPU" or "x64"
3. Solution with BihConsumerInterop assembly not deployed at all.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this through Reflector and it seems like it is dynamically loading an unmanaged DLL. The code looks for the location of the DLL to load in the Registry at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\BIH".

I have that registry path on my server, but I found something about it relating to Analysis Services which I don't currently have configured.